# find class name by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get all class that match the key by regex, so when we search for btn, we get something like this :

```
<div class="btn"> // match
    <div class="span4"> // not match
        <div class='btnbtn-success'>  // not match

        </div>
        <div class='   bbtn '>  // not match

        </div>
        <div class='   bbtn '>  // not match

        </div>
        <div class='   b  btn '> / match

        </div> 
        <div class='cbbtn '>  // not match

        </div>
        <div class='btn '>  // match

        </div>
        <div class=' bbtn '>  // not match

        </div>
        <div class='    btn'>  // match

        </div>
        <div class=" btn ">  // match

        </div>
        <div class='hello btn '>  // match

        </div>
        <div class="  btn     ">  // match

        </div>
        <div class=" btn     hello">  // match

        </div>
        <div class=" btnaa     hello">  // not match

        </div>

        <div class=" hello btn     hello"> // match

        </div>
        <div class=" hello btn">  // match

        </div>
        <div class=" hello btn     hello"> // match

        </div>

        <div class=" hello btn  ">  // match

        </div>
        <div class=" btna ">  // not match

        </div>
        <div class=" btna-success ">  // not match

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what is best regex to find **btn** class name in the code?

Comment: What about the div with two classes, does that match or not?

Comment: Is your html the current document?

Comment: @TomFenech if ('btn btn') then match ;

Comment: It is not important what the tag is

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry me, I updated the source code

Comment: Please edit your question to give an example _output._ E.g., do you want an array of references to the DOM elements that have the `btn` class, or are you trying to find out what other class(es) elements with `btn` have, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure if you want only the divs or the class names. But I ll give it a shot
something like this I suppose:

```
/(.*[\s+\"\']btn[\s+\"\'].*)/g
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/fD6fC4

Feel free to ask any query or clarifications

**Updated answer**

I am editing the regex to make it look a bit complex one but it will cover the cases people have mentioned in comments. Thank you people for your comments in improving it.

improved regex : `/(?=<[^>]+(?=[\s+\"\']btn[\s+\"\']).+)([^>]+>)/g`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/qH2hZ2

Comment: yes, that extacly what I want, also not to forget add class= :D

Comment: yes, I see, but as I was looking for class names, I said that

Comment: Hmm, so what about `<p>Let's have class="btn" in content.</p>`?

Comment: Also something that I would like to be fixed, it that it gets whole line not the matched items

Comment: do you want to match only the class name ? a sample output will be really helpful

Comment: @Ata please check the solution now if it is okay for you

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not require Regular Expressions.  You have not said what the input is (A browser DOM?  A JavaScript string of the HTML?) or what format you want the output to be (a DOM Collection?  A list of matching strings?).

You can just use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) to satisfy your example.

Unless you're iterating through all elements in the DOM and testing the classnames with a regex if(/\bbtn\b/.test(element.className)), the regex is going to pick things up that aren't really inside HTML class attribute values (unless your HTML is always constrained in some way to make this impossible).

Answer (score 0):

I think with jQuery a majority of the complexity will be hidden:

This snippet/regexp might solve your issues:

```
([\\W]btn\\b)|^btn$
```

I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5kTBX/ (I renamed the parent class to **btn2** in order to show the correct functioning of the regexp.

Please let me know if there is some issue or improvements.